# Writing to a csv file in python (if can be opened by others)

Tags: python, csv

I'm writing data to a csv file with python. The file will log data and can be opened by other people. If someone has the file open, python is unable to write to the file (access denied).

What is the best way to account for this?

Comment: Do you want to check if the file is writable?  What operating system are you on?

Comment: Do you want to keep on checking for file access if you get access denied? Or are you ok with discarding that particular log?

Comment: I'm on windows. Ideally I would write to the file no matter if someone had it open. If this isn't possible, I guess I could check if it is writable, and throw an error. The problem is that the file I'm writing to is on a shared server.

Comment: I can only discard the log if all the previous information is saved in the new one